# Make scrollable Text inside container in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a scrollable Text inside a view:

```
// other widgets,

SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    height: 200,
    child: Text(
      "Long text here which is longer than the container height"))),

// other widgets
```

The text is longer than the height of its parent container, but for some reason the text is not scrollable although it is wrapped inside `SingleChildScrollView`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try to add `scrollDirection` (horizontal):

```
SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Container(
      height: 200,
      child: Text(
          "Long text here which is longer than the container height")))
```

Default is vertical.

Or if you want to have with your height then you have to change the order (`SingleChildScrollView` inside `Container`):

```
Container(
    height: 200,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Text(
            "Long text here which is longer than the container height")))
```

Comment: thanks but I want it vertically. Interestingly though it works horizontally as you describe. It's just not what I want.

Comment: Why is the order different in this case though? I'd like to understand

Comment: Because the Container height is constant and it is visible on the screen so the scroll isn't needed. The Text is limited by Container, so if the Text is outside the Container then the Text need to be scrolled.
Clear? :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve vertical text scrolling, try putting Text widget directly inside SingleChildScrollView, instead of using a container.